# Plone 4.2.5: Disallowed to paste item(s)

Tags: plone

Today I upgrade plone from 4.1.4 to latest 4.2.5 through buildout. Everthing works except paste. When I paste a page to a folder, traceback shows:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 33, in folder_paste
   - <FSControllerPythonScript at /keti/folder_paste used for /keti/switch1>
   - Line 33
Exception: Disallowed to paste item(s).
```

I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error is thrown, if the 'allowed content types to add' are restricted, so I doubt a correlation of your problem with the upgrade and rather suspect a simple configuration-setting as the cause:

Go to

http://yourhost.org:8888/yourSiteId/portal_types/Folder/manage_propertiesForm

Look, if 'Filter content types' is checked.

If yes, either uncheck or define the allowed types in the widget below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think I find the reason: "Add new" only appear on the frontpage, but disppear on other folders.  I am the admin for the plone site, how to let it show?

Comment: Can have various reasons, just to exclude the one I mentioned: Did you check the config-options as adviced in the answer?

Comment: I do uncheck 'Filter content types' and select file, document, folder in the widget below. But error goes on and "Add new" only appear on the frontpage, but disppear on other folders.

Comment: Maybe the migration from the "Large Plone Folder" to "Folder" content type failed. Is the "Large Plone Folder" content type still listed in portal_types? If not, maybe try copying the Folder type into an id of "Large Plone Folder" to fix functionality of your existing folders on the site.

Comment: @vangheem: +1 for pointing this important information out. I suspected also a different contenttype but being spoiled of the P-4.2-series by now, didn't come up with this 'historical' detail ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ida Ebkes did get the point. So I unchecked 'Filter content types' and select file, document, folder in the widget below in portal_types/Plone%20Site/manage_propertiesForm . But it works for frontpage. So If I want "Add new" appear global, I have to check "Implicitly addable" in every content type page under portal_types.

Thanks,

Hugo

Comment: Glad you're able to proceed. So, the cause was the setting 'Implicitly addable' of each contenttype, not 'Filter contenttypes'. Thanks for clarifying.